# In Classic Traveller, how to handle overflows on the tables?

Tags: traveller, random-generation

I am generating a solar system following the procedure in Classic Traveller Book 6: Scouts. This entails rolling on many tables.

The first table is representative: it has lines for results 0-12. The rolls for companion stars take the results for primary stars as an input. This is very likely to generate results > 12.

There is a general rule for results below 0 (treat them as 0), but no general rule for results off the top of the table (at least, not that I have found).

If I just treat rolls greater than 12 as 12, I will get an overwhelming proportion of dwarf stars. That doesn’t seem right, but there are also no other obvious answers.

What is the “correct” way to interpret results off the top of the table?

Answer (score 2):

In general, the only sensible option is to stop at the last row of the table.

In the particular case of companion sizes, you could "wrap around" the table, such that a 13 result was read from the same row as the primary, a 14 from the next row, and so on; while dwarf companions are probably the most common in reality, many binaries do have companion stars of comparable size to their primaries. This certainly isn't a general rule for Traveller tables, though.